# Fetch data from SQL Server 2008 into TextBoxes in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have written the following code to search and fetch data from database into textboxes in my c# forms application on `MouseLeave` event but facing issues in fetching. Can anyone suggest changes to the code and the best way of doing it?

My code

```
private void TxtNameUpdate_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Mainform = new Form1(Login);
        string FetchClient = "select * from Clients where FirstName='" +TxtNameUpdate +"'";
        DataSet ds= new DataSet();
        adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(FetchClient, con);
        adp.Fill(ds);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TxtNameUpdate.Text = ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString();
            TxtClientTypeUpdate.Text = ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows[i]["ClientType"].ToString();
            TxtLnameUpdate.Text = ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows[i]["LastName"].ToString();
            TxtEmailUpdate.Text = ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows[i]["Email"].ToString();
            TxtUsernameUpdate.Text = ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows[i]["Username"].ToString();

            TxtDobUpdate.Text = ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows[i]["DateOfBirth"].ToString();
            TxtAddressUpdate.Text = ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();
            TxtPhoneUpdate.Text = ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows[i]["PhoneNo"].ToString();
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The main problem with your code is that you repeatedly overwrite your textboxes so they will always end up with the last value in your datatable. Put you textboxes in some kind of grid.

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: @BenRobinson Thanks for replying.Can you provide a code snippet to implement the same?

Comment: @RohitGupta I am not getting data in my TextBoxes

Comment: shouldn't this be like `"select * from Clients where FirstName='" +TxtNameUpdate.Text +"'";`

Comment: also put a condition before the loop `if(ds.Tables["Clients"].Rows.Count > 0)` this will ensure you have data in datatable before you try to read it.

Comment: Also what happens if the name in the TxtNameUpdate.Text is not found in the database? I think Rohit Gupta has provided the right clue.

Comment: @RohitGupta Thanks for the solutions and I have written 
"select * from Clients where FirstName='" +TxtNameUpdate.Text +"'";

Comment: are you getting rows in data table ?